# Error in deserializing body of request message for operation for create folder

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web, opentext

App.config:

```
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Authentication" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Collaboration" />
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_DocumentManagement" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="2:10:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_MemberService" />
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_WorkflowService" />
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ContentService" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="2:10:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483648" useDefaultWebProxy="true" transferMode="Streamed" messageEncoding="Mtom" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://kbg1oecwp1.kongsberg.fmcweb.com/cws/DocumentManagement.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_DocumentManagement" contract="CWS.DocumentManagement" name="BasicHttpBinding_DocumentManagement" />
      <endpoint address="http://kbg1oecwp1.kongsberg.fmcweb.com/cws/Authentication.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Authentication" contract="CWS.Authentication" name="BasicHttpBinding_Authentication" />
      <endpoint address="http://kbg1oecwp1.kongsberg.fmcweb.com/cws/Collaboration.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Collaboration" contract="CWS.Collaboration" name="BasicHttpBinding_Collaboration" />
      <endpoint address="http://kbg1oecwp1.kongsberg.fmcweb.com/cws/ContentService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ContentService" contract="CWS.ContentService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ContentService" />
      <endpoint address="http://kbg1oecwp1.kongsberg.fmcweb.com/cws/MemberService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_MemberService" contract="CWS.MemberService" name="BasicHttpBinding_MemberService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

The used service is "BasicHttpBinding_DocumentManagement".

The code to create a folder with the metadata details

```
                folderResult = documentManagementClient.CreateFolder(ref oAuth, Convert.ToString(filteredDataTable.Rows[i]["cmthistory"]) == "C" ? parentId :
                    subFolderId, folderName,
                     docType != "Correspondence" ?
                    filteredDataTable.Rows[i]["DocTitle"].ToString() : filteredDataTable.Rows[i]["corressubject"].ToString(), folderMetadata);
```

upon executing the above step the following error threw

**Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'CreateFolder'.**

The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message:
Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'AddArticle'.
The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while
reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the
MaxStringContentLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object
used when creating the XML reader.
Line 60, position 267.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WCF: maxStringContentLength always set to 8192](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065543/wcf-maxstringcontentlength-always-set-to-8192)

Comment: I tried this but didn't work

Comment: You can take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654892/the-maximum-string-content-length-quota-8192-has-been-exceeded-while-reading